# Why is my Dictionary<string, string> case insensitive by default?

Tags: c#, dictionary, case-sensitive

It's my understanding that key checks in Dictionary are case sensitive by default but it appears, at least in my software that this isn't the case. In order to get a case sensitive key check for TryGetValue and Contains, I have to construct my Dictionary as follows:

```
Dictionary<string, string> a = new Dictionary<string,string>(StringComparer.Ordinal);
```

So was I wrong about this? Is dictionary case-insensitive by default?

Comment: Can't remember exactly, but it was either Add was and ContainsKey wasn't or vice versa. Either way it was very irritating...

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: I really don't think that's the case.

Comment: The answer is because I'm an idiot.  Thanks for your replies and I apologise for wasting your time.  Will delete the question :p.

Comment: `Dictionary<string, X>` uses ordinal comparisons by default - if you're going to claim otherwise, it would be *really* helpful to demonstrate that.

Comment: @Robinson: With respect to the upvotes I received here, I'd prefer if you didn't, but of course, as the question doesn't provide any evidence why you think dictionary *is* case-sensitive, deleting the question is fine for the public benefit, so I do not protest.

Comment: I'll root around in my code when I get back on to my windows box, as I said can't remember exactly. I Distinctly remember getting key already exists errors, course that could have been me checking for A and adding 'a'....

Comment: A generic dictionary is generic and doesn't have a special case for string but strings do have a specialised implementation of equals.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, [`Dictionary<string, string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is not case-insensitive by default.

This can be easily shown with this little application:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class MainClass
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var newDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        newDict.Add("a", "x");
        Console.WriteLine(newDict.ContainsKey("a"));
        Console.WriteLine(newDict.ContainsKey("A"));
        newDict.Add("A", "y");
        Console.WriteLine(newDict.ContainsKey("a"));
        Console.WriteLine(newDict.ContainsKey("A"));
        Console.WriteLine(newDict.Count);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
True
False
True
True
2
```

Explanation:

- At first, key `a` is added.
- `ContainsKey` is used to check whether keys `a` and `A` are found. Only the former is.
- Then, `Add` is used to add key `A`. It does not complain, i.e. it does not think that key already exists.
- In the end, `Count` is used to check for the total number of dictionary entries and it correctly outputs `2`, namely `A` and `a`.

Comment: +1 for 'correctly'. I assume I can trust the `Count` property ;).

Comment: A generic dictionary is generic and doesn't have a special case for `string`, or any other descendant of `object` but, `string` does have a specialised implementation of `bool Equals(object)` and `int GetHashCode()`.

Comment: @Jodrell: True, I clarified the wording (by referring specifically to `Dictionary<string, string>` in the beginning), as only `string`-keyed dictionaries were considered in the question.

Answer (score 2):

A generic dictionary constructor [`IDictionary<TKey, TValue>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x525za90%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) will use whatever implementation of [`bool Equals(object obj)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [`int GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is provided on the instances of `TKey`.

For `string` this implementation is functionaly equivalent to the implementation provided by [`EqualityComparer<string>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which is functionality equivalent to [`StringComparer.Ordinal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.ordinal.aspx).

---

As you state in the question, you can use an alternative overload of the dictionary constructor to supply an [`IEqualityComparer<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) implementation that will be used as an alternative.